# Why am I not authorized? docker: you are not authorized to perform this operation: server returned 401

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY target/pichk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/app/

CMD ["java","-jar","pichk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
EXPOSE 8090
```

When I run image

```
docker run -p 8090:8090 pichk:001
```

I got error

```
docker: you are not authorized to perform this operation: server returned 401.
```

I am adding target permissions line

```
drwxrwxr-x   9 miki miki  4096 Jan  4 13:59 target/
```

docker inspect shows

```
"ContainerConfig": {
    "Hostname": "a85050e37362",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
```

What could cause this issue?

Comment: What is the exact command you tried to run?

Comment: as @Debendra pointed, what is the command and are you using a private artifactory / container registry (ECR, Jfrog, hub.docker..) . In that case, then 401 means invalid credentials.

Comment: @aamdevsecops I added the command.I also exposed 8090 port.

Comment: @Debendra I added the command.I also exposed 8090 port

Comment: @aamdevsecops I am running on my local Ubutnu,image is here.

Comment: @RichardRublev just to clear something out of the way: is docker daemon running?... and is it eventually working with  ``` 
sudo docker run -p 8090:8090 pichk-0.0.1
```

Comment: @aamdevsecops The same,docker daemon is running.

Comment: @aamdevsecops I was meessing up today something with gpg and git config,I will try to sort this out.

Comment: @RichardRublev please let us know what the issue was

Comment: @aamdevsecops still trying to find out.

Comment: @RichardRublev if you're forking and cloning a public repo from github, paste the link so we can test locally

Comment: @aamdevsecops here https://github.com/MilenkoMarkovic/intens-api-2022.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250939/discussion-between-aamdevsecops-and-richard-rublev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a hub.docker.com account which comes with one free repository.

Then proceed with the steps below:

Here is my test Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY target/aamdevsecops-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/app/

CMD ["java","-jar","aamdevsecops-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Of course, i changed the `<name>`, `<version>` and `<artifactoryId>` in pom.xml file to match my Dockerfile.

First, i built the package locally by issuing this command on the intense-api git project folder:

```
mvn package
```

Then, I built the docker image out of it:

docker build -t aamdevsecops:1.1.1 .

then logged in to docker with my hub.docker.com credentials.

```
docker login # you will be prompted for credentials of hub.docker.com account
```

tagged the image: `docker tag <Image ID> aamdevsecops/devops-bootcamp:latest`

then: `docker push aamdevsecops/devops-bootcamp:1.1.1`

Finally, I did:

```
docker run --name aamdevsecops -p 8090:8090 aamdevsecops/devops-bootcamp:latest
```

And here's the result:

[image]

dissecting what terms mean:

```
docker tag <image id> aamdevsecops/devops-bootcamp:latest
```

- tags the image id locally created with `docker build -t` command, adds
  a tag to it. (a version).

```
docker push aamdevsecops/devops-bootcamp
```

- pushes the image into hub.docker.com

`docker run --name aamdevsecops -p 8090:8090 aamdevsecops/devops-bootcamp:latest`

- runs the container from the remote repository created on hub.docker.com

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the variable `DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST` is enabled or not:

```bash
echo $DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST
```

If the above shows 1, it means it is enabled and you should disable it by setting it to 0:

```bash
export $DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST = 0
```

Your `docker run` command should work now.